# Comparing user input to a key in a dictionary

Tags: python, loops, dictionary, for-loop, if-statement

I'm trying to compare user input to keys within a dictionary, magicSpells. However, when I try to run this code, the for loop defaults to the else statement instead of doing as what I intend for it to do. How should I adjust this code?

Thank you.

```
spellClassMage = raw_input("What type of mage? ").lower() 

for userinput in spellClassMage:
            if userinput in magicSpells: 
                player[name] = randHealthMage, spellClass, score    
            else:
                print("That isn't a listed type!")
```

Comment: `spellClassMage` is a string, so your loop over it (`for userinput in ...`) returns single characters.  Is that what you expect?

Comment: Oh, no. I'm trying to return the entire word..so if user inputs "water" then it'll compare water to the dictionary.

Comment: Given an example of input you want to process ... eg is it only a single word, or can it be multiple space separated words for example.

Comment: Hey, I actually figured it out, I edited my OP.

Comment: Instead of adding the solution to the question and editing the title, please post the answer (or undelete the one you have already posted) and accept it by clicking on the tick that appear under the arrows for voting.

Comment: Woops, apologies. Updated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out the solution to my problem. I had to change the keys in my dictionary to all upper case to match the .upper() attached to spellClassMage:

```
spellClassMage = raw_input("What type of mage? ").upper() 

userinput = spellClassMage.split()

for word in userinput:
            if word in magicSpells: 
                player[name] = randHealthMage, spellClass, score    
            else:
                print("That isn't a listed type!")
```

Answer (score 0):

That should work for the if-Statement. But i don't really know, where you are going with the Rest, as the Input doesn't seem to affect the other variables.

```
spellClassMage = raw_input("What type of mage? ").lower() 

if spellClassMage in magicSpells: 
    player[name] = randHealthMage, spellClass, score    
else:
    print("That isn't a listed type!")
```

Also, if 'player' is a dict, you should try this instead:

```
player[name] = [randHealthMage, spellClass, score]
```

---

Oh, one more thing. If dealing with inputs, that can be wrong, a while loop is handy. So it doesnt cause errors later in ther program.

```
while True:
    spellClassMage = raw_input("What type of mage? ").lower() 

    if spellClassMage in magicSpells: 
        player[name] = [randHealthMage, spellClass, score]
        break
    else:
        print("That isn't a listed type, try again!")
```

Comment: The other variables aren't pasted into the code, but they have a purpose in my program. Also, why is it better if I put brackets around the values for player[name]?